# Regular Expression For Alphanumeric String With At Least One Alphabet Or Atleast One Numeric In The String

Tags: c#, regex

To test one alphanumeric string we usually use the regular expression `"^[a-zA-Z0-9_]*$"` (or most preferably `"^\w+$"` for C#). But this regex accepts numeric only strings or alphabet only strings, like `"12345678"` or `"asdfgth"`.

I need one regex which will accept only the alphanumeric strings that have **at-least one alphabet and one number**. That is to say by the regex `"ar56ji"` will be one of the correct strings, not the previously said strings.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you trying to enforce some kind of password rules?  If so, please consider not doing it at all.

Comment: No, this is not for any password match. I need this for a string field which will uniquely identify an entity over the whole application. As it's given by user so, by client requirement I thought that regex would be a good option for this.

Comment: http://www.rubular.com/r/wdmyC43XGq

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This should do it:

```cs
if (Regex.IsMatch(subjectString, @"
    # Match string having one letter and one digit (min).
    \A                        # Anchor to start of string.
      (?=[^0-9]*[0-9])        # at least one number and
      (?=[^A-Za-z]*[A-Za-z])  # at least one letter.
      \w+                     # Match string of alphanums.
    \Z                        # Anchor to end of string.
    ",
    RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace)) {
    // Successful match
} else {
    // Match attempt failed
}
```

**EDIT 2012-08-28** Improved efficiency of lookaheads by changing the lazy dot stars to specific greedy char classes.

Comment: VERY helpful and instructive +1.  Thank you for posting it.

Comment: A very good regex for my purpose. I used some what modified version: `"^(?=.*?[0-9])(?=.*?[A-Za-z])[a-zA-Z0-9_]+$"`. Actually I'm taking this as a simple string, so it says, \W as an 'Invalid Escape Sequence'. 
Thanks.

Comment: ridgerunner: Good. This works fine. How to impose length constraint in this RegEx? Suppose the string must be of exactly 8 characters in length.

Comment: Got it. `^(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[0-9])[A-Za-z0-9]{8}$` this will check for at least one number, at least one CAPS Alphabet and at least one small alphabet. and also checks for the length.

Answer (score 1):

Try this out:

```
"^\w*(?=\w*\d)(?=\w*[a-zA-z])\w*$"
```

There is a good article about it here:
http://nilangshah.wordpress.com/2007/06/26/password-validation-via-regular-expression/

Comment: This regex also works. But I think there is no need to add `\W*` to begin and end of the regex. One `\W*` should be sufficient at the begin or at the end.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
"^[a-zA-Z0-9_]*([a-zA-Z][0-9]|[0-9][a-zA-Z])[a-zA-Z0-9_]*$"
```

This will match:

```
<zero-or-more-stuff>
EITHER <letter-followed-by-digit> OR <digit-followed-by-letter>
<zero-or-more-stuff>
```

By ensuring you have either a **digit followed by letter** or a **letter followed by digit**, you are enforcing the requirement to have at least one digit and at least one letter. Note that I've left out the `_` above, because it wasn't clear whether you would accept that as a letter, a digit, or neither.

Comment: string pwd = "a1111111"; //Should pass but it doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one `^([a-zA-z]+[0-9][a-zA-Z0-9]*)|([0-9]+[a-zA-z][a-zA-Z0-9]*)$`

Answer (score 0):

Simple is better.  If you had a hard time writing it originally, you're (or some other poor sap) is going to have a hard time maintaining it or modifying it.  (And I think that I see some possible holes in the approaches listed above.)

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

boolean IsGoodPassword(string pwd){
    int minPwdLen = 8;
    int maxPwdLen = 12;
    boolean allowableChars = false;
    boolean oneLetterOneNumber = false;
    boolean goodLength = false;

    string allowedCharsPattern = "^[a-z0-9]*$";

    //Does it pass the test for containing only allowed chars?
    allowableChars = Regex.IsMatch(pwd, allowedCharsPattern , RegexOptions.IgnoreCase));

    //Does it contain at least one # and one letter?
    oneLetterOneNumber = Regex.IsMatch(pwd, "[0-9]")) && Regex.IsMatch(pwd, "[a-z]", RegularExpressions.IgnoreCase));

    //Does it pass length requirements?
    goodLength = pwd.Length >= minPwdLength && pwd.Length <= maxPwdLength;

    return allowableChars && oneLetterOneNumber && goodLength;
}
```

Comment: I'm not going to use this to match any good password. Your approach is good but this gonna take a good time to call back to server and then give an error on the browser. So, it's good to use a regex and attach it to the control itself in a silverlight page. That will be much faster, as it will be checked at the client side. Any way, what are the holes, you have seen, in the above regexes? ridgerunner has given a good one. Thanks.